# Is there a way to run uninstallers from an installer in WiX?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a WiX based installer for a suite of applications. It replaces a bunch of old installers where each application in the suite had its own InstallShield based installer.

I would like the WiX installer to find any old InstallShield based installations and run their respective uninstallers. I have tried this:

```
<Property Id="OLD_APPLICATION_A_UNINSTALLSTRING">
  <RegistrySearch Id="OldAppAUninstallString" Root="HKLM" 
   Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{$(var.OldAppAInstallerGUID)}"
   Name="UninstallString" Type="raw"/>
</Property>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="UninstallAppA" Before="InstallInitialize">
    NOT Installed AND OLD_APPLICATION_A_UNINSTALLSTRING
  </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<CustomAction Id="UninstallAppA" Directory="System32"
 ExeCommand="[OLD_APPLICATION_A_UNINSTALLSTRING] /qn" Execute="immediate" Return="check"/>
```

This results in a failed installation and error status 1618: "Another installation is already in progress. Complete that installation before proceeding with this install." Only one other installation is in progress, this installation...

Is there a way to run uninstallers from an installer in WiX?

I also have a bootstrapper and maybe I should run these uninstallations from there somehow. But I want to run them as late as possible in case the user cancels the installation. If that happens it doesn't look too good if the old application suite is gone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MSI there is a mutex that prevents two installation transactions (execute sequence) running at the same time hence your error.

You can use additional Upgrade elements to seek them out by UpgradeCode / Version / Lanugage and cause their removal during your installation transaction.

Comment: Do you have an example how to use MajorUpgrade in this way? My understanding of that element is that it uses the UpgradeCode of its parent Product element to find one old product. I have about ten different "upgrade codes"/GUIDs of the InstallShield installations to look for (and uninstall). WiX documentation doesn't give much help for this scenario.

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad. MajorUpgrade is a higher level abstraction that makes certain assumptions such as using your own UpgradeCode.   Use the Upgrade element instead (answer updated).  You would need 10 Upgrade elements each searching for products that match the 10 different UpgradeCode families.

Comment: I haven't yet got it working, but you explained why my solution didn't work and the Upgrade element seems to be the right way to go. Maybe I'm using the wrong GUID to find the old InstallShield installations. I accept this as an answer.